# Displaying API Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-api

I am trying to render different pieces of data from the GIT API and am currently unable to evaluate what my problem is. I cannot get the data to display. all i can do is look at it in the elements tab of my local host. Am i routing it incorrectly ? If not, what could be the problem ?

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

const urlForUsername = username =>
  `https://github.com/api/v3/users/${username}/events`;
   class AssociateIdentification extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       requestFailed: false
    };
  }
   componentDidMount() {
    fetch(urlForUsername(this.props.username))
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error('Network requst failed');
        }
         return response;
      })
      .then(d => d.json())
      .then(d => {
        this.setState({
          githubData: d
        });
      }, () => {
        this.setState({
          requestFailed: true
        });
      } );
   }

  render() {

    if (!this.state.githubData) return <p> Loading...</p>;
    if (this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed!</p>;

    return (
      <div>
```

this right here is what I think might be wrong, the way im routing it but im not entirely sure.

```
 {this.state.githubData.actor}  {this.props.username} 
      </div>
        );
      }
    }

 export default (AssociateIdentification);
```

Anything helps! thank you!

This is what I get with comment suggested console log

```
Promise {<resolved>: Array(6)}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(6)
 0: {id: "11174255", type: "PushEvent", actor: {…}, repo: {…}, payload: {…}, …}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: It can render a simple text? (if you remove the api call)

Comment: yes, upon removing the api call. the Failed function will display "Failed!" in place of what should be displaying the api data. @bntzio

Comment: do a `console.log` in `.then(d => d.json())` like `.then(d => console.log(d.json())` what you get?

Comment: set your state in there, instead of the `console.log` (but access the property you want to set in state) example: `this.setState({ githubData: d.json().repo_name })`

Comment: I added 1 of the 6 arrays from the console log in the original post. they are at the bottom. @bntzio

Comment: look at my comment above